# Coding a loop of polynomial with a given X to find f(x) in Java

Tags: java, function, loops, polynomial-math

So I have trouble coding a loop of a polynomial with a given x to find f(x) in java.
To put it simply, for example, I have an array of f(x) = C[0]*x^n + C[1]*x^(n-1).......C[n]n, how would I code a loop to find f(x)  with the user's input of x?
Attached below is my incomplete function

```
static double poly(double[] C, double x){
            int n=C.length-1;
            int K;
            double sum=0.0;
            //loop is supposed to go here
            return sum;
}
```

Comment: i hope you aren't us to do your homework ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to increment the variable sum by each term in the polynomial i.e.

```
Sum += C[i]×(x^(n-i)).
```

So loop from i= 0 to n with the above increment operation.

Comment: I do not think that `n^(x-i)` denotes the correct power of `x`.

Comment: Agreed on that. I was not using it as the operator, but as the exponent notation.

Comment: You have written n to the power of x-i, what you need is x to the power of n-i, i.e., x^(n-i).

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
 static double poly(double[] C, double x){
                int n=C.length-1;
                int K;
                double sum=0.0;
                /***********/
                int i=0;
                for (k=n ,k>0;k--)
                 {
                 sum= c[i]*pow(x,k)+ sum;
                 i++;
                 }
                return sum;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You do this most efficiently using the Horner scheme.

```
C[n]+C[n-1]*x+...+C[0]*x^n 
= 
C[n]+x*(C[n-1]+x*(C[n-2]+...x*C[0]))
```

or as a loop

```
pol=C[0]
for k = 1 to n do
    pol *=x
    pol += C[k]
end for
return pol
```